# How to pass a self invoking function as a function argument in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code where I am using the arrow functions to get my work done. This works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox as they support arrow functions.

```
this._subscription = this._modal.shown.subscribe(() => this._el.nativeElement.focus());
```

But, this doesn't work properly in IE 11. So, I am trying to convert this arrow function into an anonymous self invoking function. I did the following:

```
this._subscription = this._modal.shown.subscribe((function(){ this._el.nativeElement.focus()})());
```

But the above code isn't working. Am I doing something wrong? How can I do this. Any suggestions and help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to pass it, why are you invoking it immediately? The arrow function isn't immediately invoked.

Comment: So, how can I do the equivalent of the first code bit in the next code bit? @squint

Comment: @Marley Don't immediately execute the function, remove the `()` at the end in `(function(){ ... })()` so the anonymous function is not invoked. In your first code snippet you are giving the function reference and not calling it.

Comment: when you Use Arrow function there is no need to bind the function.try to use Arrow function in the name less functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
this._subscription = this._modal.shown.subscribe((function(){ this._el.nativeElement.focus();}).bind(this));
```

Here, as @harmic mentioned in the above answer's comment, this would no longer be referencing the previous value, as the scope changes in this case. So, you got to bind this to make it work.